# Products, attributes, and options schema for a marketplace

Tags: database-design, schema

I've been trying to figure out the best way to implement a table design for products for a marketplace-type app (think amazon).

I'm going to upload a bunch of products for sellers to add to their inventory, then later I will add some way for them to add their own products that would require approval by an admin.

For now, the schema I have now is this: https://drawsql.app/teams/justme-15/diagrams/vbase

[image]

In my project

- Sellers can have multiple stores
- Stores's inventory items are based on SKUs
- Products are "base products", without any options
- Products have attributes, like "brand", "manufacturer", things that don't vary per product.
- Products have SKUs, which are essentially a combination of selected options. This helps with tracking inventory, and I'm sure orders.
- Each store can have its own pricing per product.
- Each category has its own set of options, I did this so that in the front end if I change a product's category, I can query that category's options and set the product's options accordingly. (I will most likely do the same with the attributes table).

My main difficulty is trying to figure out what to link options and attributes to, do I link them to the SKU like I'm doing above? I've seen other posts here that link them to the base product *and* the SKU, but I don't understand why link to the base product.

I've only been learning SQL and database design for a couple of months now, but this past week has been the hardest with being stuck trying to figure this out. Would really appreciate any advice or any mistakes I'm not seeing, or you think I would run into in the future.